# unable to loacate in selelium python {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="downloadButton"]"} (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code and it only opens chrome.Does not click on button id that i gave.CAn anyone please help me with this.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/SeleniumDriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#download")
my_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'downloadButton')
my_element.click()
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is inside of an `iframe`, in which case you have first switch to the `iframe` and then access the element inside of it.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "downloadButton").click()
```

imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I am a new learner to selenium. It would be a very big help if you can suggest me any resources.